# Why can security guards/bar bouncers physically remove a person and it's not considered battery?

Tags: canada, police, assault, battery, self-defense

This is a follow up to this question about [when someone can use force on another person](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/6132/when-can-someone-whos-not-a-police-officer-use-physical-force). Are security guards or bouncers, such as at a concert or night club, given special privileges since they work at the venue?

Let's say there's a drunk person or someone starting a fight. I've seen bouncers put people in wrestling holds and throw them out. Is this legal because technically they are just removing them from the premises and there's no battery?

If security guards are allowed to do this then what's stopping a random jerk from throwing someone out of a grocery store by shoving them out?

Comment: Not enough for an answer but there's probably a "reasonable person" test involved here - it is reasonable for a bouncer to throw an unruly patron out of an establishment (that is the bouncer's job and why the bouncer is there; the bouncer is known to the establishment) and it may or may not be reasonable for a customer to throw a jerk out of a grocery store (it's not the customer's job, the owner has no idea who the customers are, getting thrown out of a grocery store is not customary, etc.)

Comment: It is battery, but the defense is once the proprietor has rescinded the invitation of the patron, they're trespassing.

Comment: In UK this could be assault, but legal defence can be self defence or defence of another or group. As long as force is proportionate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm based in England, but I'm sure the principle is similar in Canada.

The night club or concert venue is private property. When someone owns or rents private property one of the main things they are buying is the right to control who is present on that property, and generally they can use reasonable force to remove people who are not authorised.

Security guards generally act as agents for a property owner, tenant or similar.

Comment: The principle is similar in Canada. I can vouch for that :)